# SSH executing create user command and send command if user exists

Tags: perl, ssh, centos6

I have a website that send commands to a server via SSH2

Im trying to figure out 1 of 2 things.  either

A. Set a username for the registered account that sends the command (*IN SSH* if username = exist then send command else create user by $username, set privileges to execute PERL command ONLY and then send the command)

OR

B.  Set the sent perl commands pid to $username

**The basic concept of this is, I want to be able to kill the command based off of the process ID set**

OR

**register a username and let the command run there so the user can kill the commands via that unique username, but ONLY allow kill perl and perl script execution on that username.**

Example:  perl $username script.pl command command2 command3 (This sets the username for the users process ID)
Example2: kill $username (This kills the process based off of that ID)

P.S. my server that is using ssh is running CentOS 6 if that helps any?

Here is my current script which i would like to modify:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);

if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
// log in at url/ip on port 22
if(!($con = ssh2_connect("************", 22))){
echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n";
} else {
// try to authenticate with username, password
if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, "**********", "***********")) {
echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
} else {

// execute a command
if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "perl i.pl ".$_GET['command1']." ".$_GET['command2']." ".$_GET['command3']))) {
echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
} else {
echo "" . stream_get_contents($stream);

echo "Commands have been executed successfully!";
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What exactly you need the viewers to do ?
what is your problem. ?

Answer (score 1):

You can [use the id command to check if a given username exists](https://superuser.com/questions/336275/find-out-if-user-name-exists).

You can then use the useradd commands to create a new user. Check out useradd man page for the various options available.

It is not easily possible to create a user with the privilege to only execute just a single script. You can setup a chroot jail, but in most cases that's probably more trouble than it's worth. However, considering that you're trying to execute command with input from a web request, it's probably inevitable that you'll have to create a jail, because what you're trying to right now is basically opening up your remote server for malicious user to ransack to their heart's content.

You can use sudo with the -u option to run a script as another user. Example: `sudo -u username ls`

You can run a process  in the background and get the process id by using the `$!` variable. Example: `ls > /dev/null & echo $!`. This process id can be used later to kill the process. Be careful however, since process id can get recycled, you may accidentally kill the wrong process. Running the kill command as the same unprivileged user as the command itself (as opposed to a user with higher privileges) is a good idea to at least prevent the kill command from accidentally killing another user's process.

All these steps are no different whether you execute it locally or from SSH.